# Consulta MYSQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL , en donde realizo una consulta muy simple para obtener información de una solicitud. Como se observa en la QUERY, obtengo solo el mes de la fecha de inicio, mostrando el mes en ingles. Busque y encontré que con : ***SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';*** logro que me muestre los meses en español.
Lo que necesito es aplicar esto a mi consulta dentro de PHP, ya que si lo hago tal cual lo hago en MYSQL, me aparece error.

///////////CONSULTA MYSQL////////////////

```
 SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
 SELECT 
   cupos, 
   rotacion, 
   DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%M') as mes_inicio
 FROM servicio 
 WHERE 
   id_establecimiento = $id_establecimiento and estatus = 1;
```

////////////////CONSULTA EN PHP///////////////

```
  $squery= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cupos, rotacion, 
  DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%M') as mes_inicio, 
  FROM servicio 
  WHERE id_establecimiento_1 = $id_establecimiento and estatus = 1");
```

Comment: Prueba con [mysqli.multi-query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) a ver si cuela.

Comment: cuando llamas a una conexión sql esta se puede setear primero envias `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';` y después tu query, luego cierras la conección y listo.

Comment: Era muy simple la solución, pero estaba algo perdido.. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparto la solución, en el caso de que alguien necesite.

```
 $squery= mysqli_query($con,"SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");

 $squery= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cupos, rotacion, 
 DATE_FORMAT(fecha_inicio, '%M') as mes_inicio, 
 FROM servicio 
 WHERE id_establecimiento_1 = $id_establecimiento and estatus = 1");
```

Es solo ejecutar ambas query..